# add option (maxdop 1) to end of select sql query using alter function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` query which is stored somewhere I can't access it to modify it directly - I can only use the `ALTER FUNCTION` syntax to change it.

If I test out the select query adding

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

at the end of the query it works.

However, if I try to add this at the end of the `SELECT` query (or any other location really) within an `ALTER FUNCTION` call, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'

is there a way around this??

Comment: Is it an inline table valued function? If so then the definition is just expanded out into the calling query, so you can't add a query hint to it any more than you could add it to a subquery. You would need to add the hint at the end of the calling query.

Comment: it's all done via the entity framework